# Django Ajax returns whole html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to create live search filter,with ajax

```
$(function() {

$('#search-item').keyup(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/toysprices/",
        data: {
            'query' : $('#search-toy').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: searchSuccess,
        dataType: 'html'
    });
});
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    console.log(data);
}
```

and my views.py

```
f request.method == "GET":
    search_text = request.GET['query']
    if search_text:
        search_text = request.GET['query']
        statuss = Status.objects.filter(status__contains = search_text)
    else:
        statuss = Status.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'ajax_search.html', {'statuss':statuss})
```

it works correctly, but it returns whole html page, how can i make to get only part which I want to render in my template.

Comment: Does the link you're calling can return anything other than HTML ?

Comment: It returns only HTML but with correct search results.

Comment: If you don't own the server which is returning the result then all you can do is process the returned HTML with Javascript. Using jQuery would be easier.

Comment: I own server is it better to return JSON?

Comment: Yup, that's the best solution. It'll give you only the part you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning the result with JSON will solve your problem.

For Example,

## # Django view

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return_array = []
        search_text = request.GET.get('query') # Always put request.GET.get('param') instead of request.GET['param']
        if search_text:
            search_text = request.GET.get('query')
            statuss = Status.objects.filter(status__icontains = search_text)
        else:
            statuss = Status.objects.all()

        for i in statuss:
            return_sub_array = {}
            return_sub_array['status_name'] = i.status_name
            return_array.append(return_sub_array)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(return_array))
```

## # Jquery function

```
$('#search-item').keyup(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/toysprices/",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            'query' : $('#search-toy').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: function(data){
                   if(data.length > 0 )
                    {   
                            console.log(data);
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                                var obj = data[i]['status_name'];
                                console.log(obj)
                                // further logic goes here
                            }
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("No result found");
                    }
                 },
         error:function(data){
                 console.log('error')
                 console.log(data)
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: ok,comment the parseJSON and see how our function shows the output in network tab.

Comment: It gives me objects(without parseJSON) , now how can i parse or convert and bind to my table?

Comment: Edit has been made for this question

Comment: You have put contains in your query statement which is case-sensitive for search.If you need case-insensitive you can put icontains.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it is the url which you are using to call, assuming you have the following path in the url.py

```html
path('Import/', views.Import, name='import'),#.....1
path('getMetaData/', views.metaData, name='metadata'),#....2
```

and your url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/folder/Import/ is using the first path which is showing the page, if you wish to get data from ajax from the metaData function in views.py, if you use path 2 above it will give you html, so your path should be as follows:

```html
path('Import/getMetaData/', views.metaData, name='metadata'),#....3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering html and returning it in your view. Here's nothing to expect from this view other than html. In order to return JSON object as a response, your view should return response like this:

```
return JsonResponse({'statuss':statuss})
```